# Showing that two functionally dependent random variables are independent

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability, independence

Let $Z$ and $\theta \sim \text{Unif}[0, 2\pi)$ be two independent random variables, in which $Z$ has the following pdf:
$$ f_Z(z) = \begin{cases} 0, & z \leq 0 \\ ze^{-z^2/2}, & z > 0\end{cases}$$

Show that $A = Z\cos(\theta)$ and $B = Z\sin(\theta)$ are also independent.

---

My attempt was to use $f_{A,B}(a, b) = \frac{d}{db} F_{B|A}(b | a) f_A(a)$ and show that $f_{A, B}(a, b) = f_A(a) f_B(b)$, but nothing came out.

I think knowing that $Z = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2}$ would somehow help, but I can't see where to use that.

Comment: Rewrite as x and y.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor I tried writing $x/y = A/B = \tan(\theta)$, but I can't recover $\theta$ from $x/y$, because the image of $\arctan(x/y)$ is restricted to $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, whereas $\theta$ is in $[0, 2\pi)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent standard normal random variables, then using polar coordinates you can write (for any arbitrary bounded measurable function $g$)
$$
E[g(X,Y,\sqrt{X^2+Y^2})] =\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\infty g(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,r) r {e^{-r^2/2}} dr{1\over 2\pi} d\theta.
$$
This shows that the joint distribution of $(A,B,Z)$ is the same as that of $(X,Y,\sqrt{X^2+Y^2})$. In particular, $A$ and $B$ are independent.